# Boost::Asio, SSL Connection Problems

Tags: c++, boost, https, openssl, boost-asio

I tried to solve my Problem for a few days now and just can't get behind it. I try to do an SSL Connection with the Boost::Asio Library and OpenSSL. There is an Example Code, how to do this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp

It builds and runs fine and even the verifying seems to work, but when I send a simple request, nothing happens for quite a long time, and then i get an error Message: "Read Failed: short read". I guess, I'm just doing the request line itself wrong, but i can't figure out how it has to be. I tried both the following lines:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>Host: www.google.de<CR><LF>Connection: close<CR><LF><CR><LF>

GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.de\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

I can't post images, because this is my first Post, but you can find the cmd-Window here: [image: http://imgur.com/UOeENm5]

Thanks in Advance!

Update: I got it to work! :D Big thanks to sehe, i just had to change line 77 in your code from:

```
size_t request_length = strlen(request_);
```

to:

```
 size_t request_length = strlen(raw);
```

Now it works just fine,  thx for your help :)

I still don't understand, why the boost example code isn't working as intended for me..

Comment: surely you can copy/paste the ***text*** from your command box, though? Please do

Comment: Checked with openssl and inserting a simple "GET /\n" returns a 302 HTTP message.

Comment: Check your std::cin.getline. There is the key. ;)

Comment: @JonAnderOrtizDurántez I can't tell, but he likely doesn't have that. I can confirm the issue, linux64, gcc 4.8, boost 1.55.0, source **[on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2042c3d24a16c6ac)**

Comment: Thx for your answers! @JonAnderOrtizDurántez Even with this simple GET line i get the same Error.

Comment: @sehe I tried your code, but when i run it, i get an Debug Assertion Failed Error. I updated my post with it. but also thx so far :)

Comment: Good news. I found the bug in my code. There's an off-chance that you had the same bug (?) otherwise, you can use my sample to work out what you did differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah!

I've found more time and looked at it again. My code here (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2042c3d24a16c6ac) was already ***almost*** correct. Except for one really simple bug:

```
size_t request_length = strlen(request_);
```

Looks innocuous, no? Except... `request_` was uninitialized at this point. It needed to be (in context):

```
  static char const raw[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.de\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

  static_assert(sizeof(raw)<=sizeof(request_), "too large");

  size_t request_length = strlen(raw);
  std::copy(raw, raw+request_length, request_);
```

Of course, this problem did not exist in the official Boost sample you linked to (as it reads directly into the request buffer with `std::cin.getline`). However, like me, you might have made the same beginner's mistake.

Hope this helps.

Attached is a fully working demo that you van even switch to use HTTPS or not using preprocessor directive:

```
#define SEHE_USE_SSL
```

Note also, I used

```
ctx.set_default_verify_paths();
```

so you can use the default root authority certificates registered on your machine (if your openssl installation has it).

#### Full Code

```
#define SEHE_USE_SSL
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      boost::asio::ssl::context& context,
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : socket_(io_service
#ifdef SEHE_USE_SSL
            , context)
  {
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(
        boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));
#else
            )
  {
      (void) context;
#endif

    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
      // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
      // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
      // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
      // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
      // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
      // certificate authority.

      // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
      char subject_name[256];
      X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
      X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
      std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

      return true || preverified;
  }

  void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
#ifdef SEHE_USE_SSL
      if (!error)
      {
          socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                  boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      }
#else
      handle_handshake(error);
#endif
  }

  void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
      if (!error)
      {
          std::cout << "Enter message: ";
          static char const raw[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.de\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

          static_assert(sizeof(raw)<=sizeof(request_), "too large");

          size_t request_length = strlen(raw);
          std::copy(raw, raw+request_length, request_);

          {
              // used this for debugging:
              std::ostream hexos(std::cout.rdbuf());
              for(auto it = raw; it != raw+request_length; ++it)
                  hexos << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::showbase << ((short unsigned) *it) << " ";
              std::cout << "\n";
          }

          boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                  boost::asio::buffer(request_, request_length),
                  boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
      if (!error)
      {
          std::cout << "starting read loop\n";
          boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,
                  //boost::asio::buffer(reply_, sizeof(reply_)),
                  reply_, '\n',
                  boost::bind(&client::handle_read, this,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      }
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
      if (!error)
      {
          std::cout << "Reply: " << &reply_ << "\n";
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
      }
  }

private:
#ifdef SEHE_USE_SSL
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
#else
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
#endif
  char request_[1024];
  //char reply_  [1024];
  boost::asio::streambuf reply_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], argv[2]);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

        client c(io_service, ctx, iterator);

        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. I can't believe that we - independently - committed the same bug. (I was just playing along to not make you feel stupid :))