# Can Boost ASIO have a single function to return a SSL or non-SSL socket?

Tags: ssl, boost-asio

Started C++ last week and was tasked with implementing SSL into a proxy.
This code works below but seems really bloated IMHO. The only difference is just a minor change to indicate which socket to use:

```
typedef ip::tcp::socket socket_type;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Bridge> ptr_type;
typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_socket;          
...
ssl_socket   downstream_socket_;  // (SSL socket connected to client)
...

            if (sslEnabled)
            {
                downstream_socket_.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&Bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
            else
            {
                downstream_socket_.next_layer().async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&Bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to reduce the above code to this:

```
            downstream_socket().async_read_some(
                boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                boost::bind(&Bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                            shared_from_this(),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

where the new function **downstream_socket()** is defined as:

```
socket_type &Bridge::downstream_socket()
{
    if (sslEnabled)
    {
        return downstream_socket_;
    }
    else
    {
        return downstream_socket_.next_layer();
    }
}
```

I tried this overloaded function concept where if I could define a template variable "sslEnabled" to be either an int when SSL is enabled, or double for non-SSL, then I could write this:

```
socket_type& socket(double sslEnabled)
{
    return downstream_socket_->next_layer();
}      

ssl_socket& socket(int sslEnabled)
{
    return downstream_socket_;
}
```

and let the compiler figure out which overloaded function to call to return the correct socket:

```
downstream_socket(sslEnabled).async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(downstream_data_, max_data_length),
                    boost::bind(&Bridge::handle_downstream_read,
                                shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

But ran into problems defining a template variable "sslEnabled" to be either an **int** or **double** based upon SSL or non-SSL being enabled.

To determine if SSL is enabled or not, this code is called:

```
// Used to detect the start of an SSL handshake.

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    BYTE Handshake; // SSL handshake: 0x16
    BYTE TLS;       // Newest major version: 0x03
    BYTE Version;   // Version: 0x00 (SSL v3), 0x01 (TLS v1.0), 0x02 (TLS v1.1), 0x03 (TLS v1.2)
} TLSHeader;
#pragma pack(pop)
...
...
...

            TLSHeader *TLS_header = new TLSHeader;

            // Peek at incoming client data (3 bytes) to see if it might be a TLSv1.x handshake
            // and without removing it from the input queue.

            session->downstream_socket_.next_layer().async_receive(
                boost::asio::buffer(TLS_header, sizeof(TLSHeader)),
                ip::tcp::socket::message_peek,
                boost::bind(&Acceptor::handle_TLS_header,
                            this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
                            session,
                            TLS_header));
```

which calls the function below to determine the TLS handshake:

```
void Bridge::Acceptor::handle_TLS_header(const boost::system::error_code &error, const size_t &bytes_transferred, ptr_type session, TLSHeader *TLS_header)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        // Detect the start of an SSL handshake.

        if (TLS_header->Handshake == 0x16 && TLS_header->TLS == 0x03 && TLS_header->Version)
        {
            switch (TLS_header->Version)
            {
            case 0x01:
                DBOUT("TLS v1.0 Handshake Detected.");
                break;
            case 0x02:
                DBOUT("TLS v1.1 Handshake Detected.");
                break;
            case 0x03:
                DBOUT("TLS v1.2 Handshake Detected.");
                break;
            default:
                DBOUT("TLS v1.x Handshake Detected.");
                break;
            }

            DBOUT("Starting an SSL session.");

            session->sslEnabled = true;

            session->downstream_socket_.async_handshake(
                boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
                boost::bind(&Acceptor::handle_accept,                               
                            this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            session));                  
        }
        else
        {
            DBOUT("Starting a non-SSL session.");

            session->sslEnabled = false;

            boost::system::error_code error = boost::system::errc::make_error_code(boost::system::errc::success);
            handle_accept(error, session);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DBOUT("handle_TLS_header: " << error.message());

        session->close();

        delete this;
    }

    delete TLS_header;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can. You choose runtime or static polymorphism and code to the same interface/concept accordingly. If it helps, here's an answer where I have largely shared code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730448/85371 (so you know what to abstract)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it seems that code knows if it's doing SSL or not by this: #ifdef SEHE_USE_SSL. I'm wondering if I can use your approach to detect on-the-fly if SSL is enabled by peeking at the SSL handshake bytes .

Comment: Oh. That's different. You want to detect SSL use. You cannot. For that you need TLS/STARTTLS protocol. SSL is end-to-end encrypted so nothing preceeds the handshake. I suppose you can hack it but that would require "putting back" input into the stream as if it were never read. I wouldn't recommend this route without a proper protocol