# Synchronous HTTPS POST with Boost Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, http, boost, boost-asio

**When uploading a 10 MB file over HTTP using a plain socket - everything works as expected:**

```c++
string filename("c:\\test.zip");
long long fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filename);

//Read file into memory
FILE * filePointer;
fopen_s(&filePointer, filename.c_str(), "rb");
unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> charArray(new unsigned char[1024*1024*20]);
fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread_s(charArray.get(), 1024 * 1024 * 20, sizeof(unsigned char), fileSize, filePointer);

//Setup Socket
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::endpoint ep;
ep.port(90);
ep.address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"));

shared_ptr<tcp::socket> httpSocket = make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
httpSocket->connect(ep);

string PREFIX = "--";
//Use GUID as boundary
string BOUNDARY = boost::uuids::to_string(boost::uuids::random_generator()()); 
string NEWLINE = "\r\n";
int NEWLINE_LENGTH = NEWLINE.length();

//Calculate length of entire HTTP request - goes into header
long long lengthOfRequest = 0;
lengthOfRequest += PREFIX.length() + BOUNDARY.length() + NEWLINE_LENGTH;
lengthOfRequest += string("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fmChunk\"; filename=\"test.zip\"").length();
lengthOfRequest += NEWLINE_LENGTH + NEWLINE_LENGTH;
lengthOfRequest += fileSize;
lengthOfRequest += NEWLINE_LENGTH + PREFIX.length() + BOUNDARY.length() + PREFIX.length() + NEWLINE_LENGTH;

boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);

request_stream << "POST /filehandler.ashx HTTP/1.1" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Host: localhost" << NEWLINE; // << ":" << port << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "User-Agent: FilemailDesktop2Cpp" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept-Language: nb,no;q=0.8,nn;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,en;q=0.2" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0" << NEWLINE; //Disables compression
request_stream << "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Connection: close" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << lengthOfRequest << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" << BOUNDARY << NEWLINE;
request_stream << NEWLINE;

request_stream << PREFIX;
request_stream << BOUNDARY;
request_stream << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fmChunk\"; filename=\"test.zip\"";
request_stream << NEWLINE;
request_stream << NEWLINE;

auto data = request.data();
httpSocket->write_some(buffer(data));

//Send Data (Paytload)
auto bytesSent = 0;
while (bytesSent < fileSize)
{
    int bytesToSendNow = min(fileSize - bytesSent, 1024 * 100);
    httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(charArray.get() + bytesSent, bytesToSendNow));
    bytesSent += bytesToSendNow;
}

//Close request
httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(NEWLINE));
httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(PREFIX));
httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(BOUNDARY));
httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(PREFIX));
httpSocket->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(NEWLINE));

//Read Response
boost::asio::streambuf response;
read_until(*httpSocket, response, "\r\n");
string strResponse(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(response.data()), response.size());

//Check Response
if (strResponse.find("200 OK") != string::npos){
    cout << "OK";
}
else
{
    BOOST_FAIL("Upload failed");
}
```

**But doing the same upload via HTTPS doesn't work. A different port + the socket part is pretty much the entire difference.**

```c++
string filename("c:\\test.zip");
long long fileSize = boost::filesystem::file_size(filename);

//Read file into memory
FILE * filePointer;
fopen_s(&filePointer, filename.c_str(), "rb");
unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> charArray(new unsigned char[1024 * 1024 * 20]);
fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread_s(charArray.get(), 1024 * 1024 * 20, sizeof(unsigned char), fileSize, filePointer);

//Setup Socket
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::endpoint ep;
ep.port(443);
ep.address(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"));

boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ssl_socket sslSocket(io_service, ctx);
sslSocket.lowest_layer().connect(ep);
sslSocket.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
sslSocket.handshake(ssl_socket::client); 


string PREFIX = "--";
//Use GUID as boundary
string BOUNDARY = boost::uuids::to_string(boost::uuids::random_generator()());
string NEWLINE = "\r\n";
int NEWLINE_LENGTH = NEWLINE.length();

//Calculate length of entire HTTP request - goes into header
long long lengthOfRequest = 0;
lengthOfRequest += PREFIX.length() + BOUNDARY.length() + NEWLINE_LENGTH;
lengthOfRequest += string("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fmChunk\"; filename=\"test.zip\"").length();
lengthOfRequest += NEWLINE_LENGTH + NEWLINE_LENGTH;
lengthOfRequest += fileSize;
lengthOfRequest += NEWLINE_LENGTH + PREFIX.length() + BOUNDARY.length() + PREFIX.length() + NEWLINE_LENGTH;

boost::asio::streambuf request;
std::ostream request_stream(&request);

request_stream << "POST /filehandler.ashx HTTP/1.1" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Host: localhost" << NEWLINE; // << ":" << port << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "User-Agent: FilemailDesktop2Cpp" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept-Language: nb,no;q=0.8,nn;q=0.6,en-us;q=0.4,en;q=0.2" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0,deflate;q=0" << NEWLINE; //Disables compression
request_stream << "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Connection: close" << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << lengthOfRequest << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" << BOUNDARY << NEWLINE;
request_stream << NEWLINE;

request_stream << PREFIX;
request_stream << BOUNDARY;
request_stream << NEWLINE;
request_stream << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fmChunk\"; filename=\"test.zip\"";
request_stream << NEWLINE;
request_stream << NEWLINE;

auto data = request.data();
sslSocket.write_some(buffer(data));

//Send Data (Paytload)
auto bytesSent = 0;
while (bytesSent < fileSize)
{
    int bytesToSendNow = min(fileSize - bytesSent, 1024 * 100); 
    sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(charArray.get() + bytesSent, bytesToSendNow));
    bytesSent += bytesToSendNow;
}

//Close request
sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(NEWLINE));
sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(PREFIX));
sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(BOUNDARY));
sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(PREFIX));
sslSocket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(NEWLINE));


//Read Response
boost::asio::streambuf response;
read_until(sslSocket, response, "\r\n");
string strResponse(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(response.data()), response.size());

//Check Response
if (strResponse.find("200 OK") != string::npos){
    cout << "OK";
}
else
{
    BOOST_FAIL("Upload failed");
}
```

When running this code, the upload stalls at

```c++
read_until(*sslSocket, response, "\r\n");
```

If I then kill the process - the socket is closed - and the IIS Express webserver (where I have also attached a debugger) receives the request and processes it. The length of the uploaded file received by the server is always 1772261 bytes.

When trying to upload a 1MB file - the same happens, server only receives 180224 bytes.

I am able to make HTTPS GET requests using similar sslSocket code - and plain HTTP POST also works fine - so it seems to be the combination of SSL and POST that's creating some problems for me.

Is there an internal buffer/stream limit for sslSockets in Boost?

Would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: Your sample is probably miss-copy-pasted. There is no code using `sslSocket` in your question at all.

Comment: Meanwhile, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683142/boostasio-ssl-connection-problems/21730448#21730448 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730448/85371 might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - sorry the the copy/paste error. It's been corrected now.

Anyways - it turned out the problem was that I was writing (1024 * 100) bytes to socket each time - and this was too much for the sslSocket - while it worked fine for the httpSocket. Reducing it to just 1024 fixed the problem.

I really should have checked the return value of the sslSocket.write_some method to make sure the expected number of bytes were written.

[image]